# What are the keys for in Starseed Pilgrim?

Tags: starseed-pilgrim

I've just started Starseed Pilgrim, and there is one thing I don't understand.

If a plant touches a black box, the plant starts to get contaminated, one cell at a time. If the character touches a black box or a contaminated cell of a plant, the character falls in another dimension where black boxes are keys, cells of plants are empty spaces, and empty space is solid rock.

[image]

I have tried collecting as many keys as possible. But every time, I have to hold "H" to make the character die because he is stuck in the other dimension, so no progress in collecting keys.

What do they open?

Can I skip collecting them without worrying about that they might be useful later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the black box that is the key, but the star. Connect the structure to black to make that area traversible in the other dimension. Hint: You'll want to grab the key(s) and bring it/them somewhere...